# Performance - Completing string concatenations at initialization

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Underscore.js does this cool thing.  Here is their code modified.

```
NS.as(['Arguments', 'Function', 'String', 'Number', 'Date', 'RegExp'], function(name) {
    NS['is' + name] = function(obj) {
        return toString.call(obj) == '[object ' + name + ']';
    };
});
```

These functions are created on first pass and then available later for the developer.

```
NS.isFunction()
NS.isString(),
etc.
```

However, I want this value

```
'[object ' + name + ']';
```

hard coded in so that it is not calculated for each call.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the string before creating the function, and put it in a local variable. As it's a local variable in the function, each iteration will have its own value:

```
NS.as(['Arguments', 'Function', 'String', 'Number', 'Date', 'RegExp'], function(name) {

  var objName = '[object ' + name + ']';

  NS['is' + name] = function(obj) {
    return toString.call(obj) == objName;
  };

});
```

Comment: ... do you have any idea why the original author would not have done this... it is so simple and saves two string concatenations ... which are slow ... http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-string-vs-dynamic-string

Comment: ...here is more complex issue involving same ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973831/how-to-optimize-functions-using-initialize-time-configuration

Answer (score 1):

```
NS.as(['Arguments', 'Function', 'String', 'Number', 'Date', 'RegExp'], function(name) {
    var typeId = '[object ' + name + ']';
    NS['is' + name] = function(obj) {
        return toString.call(obj) == typeId;
    };
});
```